# Conversion from Spark to Pandas using pandas_api and toPandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

```
df = spark.table("data").limit(100)
df = df.toPandas()
```

This conversion using `.toPandas` works just fine as `df.limit` is just a few rows. If I get rid of limit and do `toPandas` on the whole df, I get an error *"Job aborted due to stage failure"*

I've been using `.pandas_api()`, and its been working just fine, but I can't use it on sklearn functions. I tried passing a column into `fit_transform` and I get the error: *"The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented."*

If I limit the dataset, use `toPandas`, then `fit_transform` works just fine.

How can I make this work?

I've tried this and it works:

```
df = spark.table("data").limit(100)
df = df.toPandas()
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
encoder = LabelEncoder()
df["p"] = encoder.fit_transform(df["p"])
```

removing the limit, won't let me convert to pandas. Instead, I tried the api:

```
df = df.pandas_api()
```

and it converts but then I can't pass the column into `fit_transform`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to answer your question, but I'm not sure there's a solution - here's why:

What you are trying to do with the `toPandas()` call is convert your `spark Dataframe` to a `pandas DataFrame`. This operation actually requires storing all of your data in a `pandas DataFrame` which may make your execution run out of memory - hence your `Job aborted due to stage failure`. Although the error is not explicit, it's usually a sign indicating that something went wrong in terms of memory. There are other causes, but this seems most likely given that your execution works when you call the `.limit` function (which in your case limits your dataframes to 100 rows).

Ok, so the `.toPandas()` call should return a `pandas DataFrame`. But what does `.pandas_api()` do? Well, in the context of `scikit-learn`, not exactly what you'd want. [Here's](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.pandas_api.html) the `.pandas_api()` function documentation, but note that it returns a `PandasOnSparkDataFrame` object, and `scikit-learn` may expect a `pandas Dataframe` or some `numpy array`.

Having said this, one option is to split your large `spark Dataframe` into multiple `pandas Dataframes` using the `limit` call - i.e. try getting half of all your data, see if it fails. If it does, try getting 25%, and so on. You can save the resulting `pandas DataFrames` as CSV files, reading each of the resulting CSV files into `pandas DataFrames` in a for loop, and applying the same Label Encoder sequentially. Or you could try saving all the partial `pandas DataFrames` as numpy arrays `pkl` objects, and then concatenating all the matrixes to reconstruct your data.

Not perfect solutions, but they should get you on your way to finding a solution that works for you.